# How to remove underscores from json key value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a json file like

```
{
"Asian_Cities_Countries":[
{"name":"Beijing",
"country":"China"
},
{"name":"Ankara",
"country":"Turkey"
}
],
"European_Cities_Countries":[
{"name":"Paris",
"country":"France"
},
{"name":"Madrid",
"country":"Spain"
}
]
}
```

It is just a part of a json file the actual json is quite big.
I am fetching this json through angularjs and displaying it my html page as

```
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div ng-repeat="key in notSorted(items) track by $index" class="panel panel-default menu-panel" ng-init="value = items[key]" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="menu-link" href="#{{key}}">
                <div class="panel-heading panel-types">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                    {{key}}
  </h4>
                </div></a>
                <div id="{{key}}" class="panel-collapse collapsing menu-items">
                    <div ng-repeat="item in value">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
                                <p class="item-name">
                                {{item.name}}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
                                <p>{{item.country}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now I want to remove underscores from the key value and replace it with blank spaces.How do i do it.

I tried {{key.replace('_',' ')}} . But it removes only the first underscore and not all of them.

Comment: you can use filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("ctrl" , function($scope){
  $scope.items = {
     "Asian_Cities_Countries":
           [
             {"name":"Beijing","country":"China"},
             {"name":"Ankara","country":"Turkey"}
           ],
      "European_Cities_Countries":
          [
             {"name":"Paris","country":"France"},
             {"name":"Madrid","country":"Spain"}
          ]
 };
  
  });

app.filter('removeUnderscores', [function() {
return function(string) {
    if (!angular.isString(string)) {
        return string;
    }
    return string.replace(/[/_/]/g, ' ');
 };
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in items track by $index" class="panel panel-default menu-panel" ng-init="value = items[key]" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="menu-link" href="#{{key}}">
                <div class="panel-heading panel-types">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                    {{key | removeUnderscores}}
  </h4>
                </div></a>
                <div id="{{key}}" class="panel-collapse collapsing menu-items">
                    <div ng-repeat="item in value">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
                                <p class="item-name">
                                {{item.name}}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
                                <p>{{item.country}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

try this. use a filter similar this

```
 app.filter('removeUnderscores', [function() {
return function(string) {
    if (!angular.isString(string)) {
        return string;
    }
    return string.replace(/[/_/]/g, ' ');
 };
}])
```

and in html

```
   {{key | removeUnderscores}}
```

Comment: @Gopal Chandak see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you forgot the global modifier, try this:

`key.replace(/_/g,' ')`

with "g" all occurences should be replaced

Comment: No it doesnt work. We cant use use regular expression here. I tried

Comment: why can't you use regular expressions?

Comment: See the answer given by georgeawg.

Comment: Funny. The solution still uses regexp.

Comment: Yes it uses. But the regex has been used in the controller and not in the scope. We cant use regex in the scope

Answer (score 2):

The AngularJS Docs specifically state that Angular Expressions don't include regular expressions.

> ### Angular Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions
>
> Angular expressions are like JavaScript expressions with the following differences:
>
> - **No RegExp Creation With Literal Notation:** You cannot create regular expressions in an Angular expression.

-- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angular-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions)

Instead use a custom filter as recommended by [@hadijz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3669698/hadijz)

```
app.filter('removeUnderscores', [function() {
return function(string) {
    if (!angular.isString(string)) {
        return string;
    }
    return string.replace(/[/_/]/g, ' ');
 };
}])
```

and in html

```
{{key | removeUnderscores}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a question. Why aren't you processing the json file/data within a service? This much processing (especially string replacing) isn't meant to be done in either the HTML or the controller in AngularJS. 
I'd recommend that you parse the json inside a service and then pass it to the controller. That's usually the best practice..

Please see this [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/gohinuxeva/1/edit?html,js,console,output) for reference. Thank you